# Is the java byte code independent of CPU or independent of OS?

Tags: java, jvm

I am confused about  the in-dependability of the java byte code,I see some where that is said the java byte code is independent of the **cpu** and the architecture of that, but  some times I see that is said it is independent of the **platform**(Windows,Linux,etc). which one is true? I think they are not the same, because a system with one type of  cpu can have different platforms,am I right?

can we say that if we have the same attributes of (for exmaple) Linux(the same platform), but on different cpu architectures on different systems,should  we use different JVM?

please help me about this issue
thanks  in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 3):

It's independent of both.  As long as there is a [JVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine) for that OS and CPU architecture, it can run java Bytecode.

Comment: as I found of your answer so, the jvm  is dependent on both of CPU and OS?am I right?

Comment: of course, just like every other application in existence.

Comment: @user3201263  Yep, the JVM itself is dependent on it.  There needs to be an OS-Specific implementation, but once there is the JVM allows it to run the bytecode.

Comment: thanks for your answer. so I have a question,if we have the same attributes of Linux but on different cpu architectures on different systems, we should use different JVM?

Comment: @user3201263 a different binary of the JVM, yes (one compiled for the architecture in question)

Comment: @ PeterT, thanks, yes it is true, one compiled for the different architecture,but what does it mean? "different bina ry of the JVM?" excuse me if I am  a little primary in java.

Comment: @user3201263 I just meant that they could both use the same C/C++ source code but compiling them for the different architectures would naturally result in different executable files (binaries).

Comment: using the same C/C++ source code for different platforms is impossible, if you dont abstract _EVERY_ platform-specific call.

Comment: @specializt It is fairly common practice to do that.